# How to enable autocomplete for Google Apps Script in locally-installed IDE

Tags: google-apps-script, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, clasp

I'm trying to build GAS projects locally using [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp).

Any locally-installed IDE is a huge improvement over Google's Script Editor, so the tool looks very promising. Unfortunately, the autocomplete feature for GAS services doesn't seem to be included in the package.

The documentation says:

> The Apps Script CLI uses TypeScript to provide autocompletion and linting when developing. Use an IDE like Visual Studio Code for TypeScript autocompletion.

After going through the steps and installing all required dependencies, I'm still unable to get the autocomplete feature to work. When I execute the `clasp pull` command for the existing project, it converts the ".gs" extension to ".js". The autocomplete suggestions are simply the result of parsing existing code.

For example, if I call `sheet.getRange()` somewhere in my code, then the `getRange()` method will pop up in suggestions, but I can't list available options for, say, `PropertiesService`, unless it's already used in my code.

Has anybody had any luck with enabling autocomplete feature for Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the solution that partially works, but it may not be applicable to other software. The steps below are for Visual Studio Code:

1. Install the NPM package containing type definitions for GAS using

   ```
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script
   ```
2. In your locally-saved script, create a '.js' file and type

   ```
   import 'google-apps-script';
   ```

Comment: With the latest clasp, step 2 and removing imports are not needed. They are handled automatically.

Comment: should it be installed locally or globally for it to work?

Comment: @EdgeDev you can install locally. See this guide for updated instructions:
https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md

Comment: in `Visual Studio Code`... `npm i @types/google-apps-script` works alone to add **intellisense**: no need to create an extra file to `import 'google-apps-script'` nor to add anything to `.claspignore`

Comment: @rellampec Now it sure does. It didn't as of 2018. Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: I had everything working fine with typescript for a couple days. I never did the import statement because I didn't seem to need it and then one day it suddenly required it. Couldn't find interfaces or functions defined in other files anymore. Curious if anyone knows why. Maybe vscode had just sort of remembered everything since I created it all in one session? This seemed to fix it

Answer (score 17):

This answer is a minor variation on the accepted one for IDEs/extensions which support Typescript auto completion based on `tsc`/`tsserver`:

- Install TypeScript and @types/google-apps-script

  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript
  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script
- Create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) file in your local project directory:

  ```
  { 
      "compilerOptions": {
          "checkJs": true
        }
  }
  ```
- Alternatively, If you're using [`typescript`](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md) along with javascript, then create a [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

  ```
  { 
      "compilerOptions": {
          "allowJs": true,
          "checkJs": true,
          "types": ["google-apps-script"]
        }
  }
  ```
- Include both filenames in `.claspignore`, if you're using clasp and if the file is in your local directory.
- You can also use any of this config globally, if the config is in your home/parent directory, as tsc searches for this config from project/local folder to root(in which case, you don't need to  include it in `.claspignore`).

Comment: Which IDE is this for? I'm trying to find a way to get this to work in Notepad++.

Comment: @IMThe  Should work with any ide that supports autocomplete+typescript. I'm not sure whether notepad++ supports autocomplete from typescript. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165017/) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Editor-Support#notepad)

Comment: I'm using VS Code, this solution works well, no need to create `.claspignore` because it already ignores all extensions excepting some by default. But I had a little annoying  error in `tsconfig.json`: "Cannot write '.../Code.js' because it would overwrite input file .ts". I fixed the error with `"outDir": "./built"` in `"compilerOptions"`.

Comment: Minor issue with ts types. It should be `"types": ["@types/google-apps-script"]`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using any JetBrains IDE:

Go to `Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Download...` and download the library `google-apps-script`.

[image]

Comment: This basically just installs correct @types again similarly as doing it by installing NPM deps. If you took over the set of *.gs files from the web app then this also requires going to settings `Editor - File types` and set JavaScript extension as `*.gs` so the code highlights correctly

Answer (score 6):

Try including the file name, `import.js` in `.claspignore` [(docs)](https://github.com/google/clasp#ignore-file-claspignore).

This should save some trouble deleting the file before each push every time.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer provided by Google developers in the "[TU17: Enhancing the Google Apps Script Developer Experience with clasp and TypeScript](https://youtu.be/-TtxUOd5yNI?t=779)" video.

Add a JavaScript file to your project like "appscript.js" and, in that file, add:

```
import "google-apps-script";
```

Save that file but make sure to ignore it when pushing files back to your project using a `.claspignore` file.