# Annotate variable with Google Script type in TypeScript file (using clasp)

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

I'm writing a [Google Apps Script (GAS)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) using the [clasp tool](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp), which lets you locally develop TypeScript files that compile to Google Scripts.

I imported Google Script type definitions by running `npm i -S @types/google-apps-script`, and my IDE (VS Code) does indeed seem to understand the Google Script types. I cannot, however, seem to annotate my variables with these type definition. For example,

```
let ss: Spreadsheet;
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

Is this possible to annotate my code with these imported type definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling autocomplete for Google Apps Script in locally-installed IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/enabling-autocomplete-for-google-apps-script-in-locally-installed-ide)

Comment: Related, follow-up question for me: [Abbreviate lengthy TypeScript Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198823/abbreviate-lengthy-typescript-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom type annotations can be used like this:

```
var ss: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;
```

- namespace: `GoogleAppsScript`
- module: `Spreadsheet`
- interface: `Spreadsheet`

Comment: Man! You saved me a lot of trouble. I was giving up on having typed objects in my code. This is really great thank you.

Comment: @Ashkan You shouldn't need this, if your ide is configured properly. Everything should just automatically be inferred. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/enabling-autocomplete-for-google-apps-script-in-locally-installed-ide

Comment: I'm using Typescript in Intellij Idea and the solution in that SO answer did not work for me. The only way I could get type inferring was your solution, using the fully qualified name of the Spreadsheet type.

Comment: @Ashkan Jetidea specific answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339109/). Try to troubleshoot why types aren't inferred.

Comment: @Ashkan https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-typescript.html#ws_ts_run_debug_server_side

Comment: I did install the library in intellij, that was some hidden feature I didn't know about. But still no luck, just `GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet` got better colors :) If I use `Sheet` instead of `GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet` no type is inferred and it shows error. Anyway I'm ok with this as long as I have autocomplete and intellij shows no error!

Comment: @Ashkan Consider asking a new question tagging intellij. In my environment, `GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet` works fine.