# Abbreviate lengthy TypeScript Types

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

I'm developing a [Google Apps Script (GAS)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) using Typescript (via the [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) tool).

I imported type definitions by running `npm i -S @types/google-apps-script`.

Some types are quite lengthy, for example:

```
let sheet: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet
```

Is there a way to define an abbreviation within a file? e.g.,

```
declare Sheet = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet
```

Comment: You don't have to annotate every variable. Types are inferred by default. If not, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/enabling-autocomplete-for-google-apps-script-in-locally-installed-ide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define new alias type:

```
type Sheet = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet
```