# Incompatible type notation in JSDoc for Google Apps Script online vs locally

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, google-apps-script, jsdoc, clasp

Consider the following script

```
function caller(){
  getSpreadsheet1();// only the online IDE understands this
  getSpreadsheet2();// only the local IDE (VS Code) understands this
}

/**
 * @returns {SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet}
 */
function getSpreadsheet1(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
  return spreadsheet;
}

/**
 * @returns {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet}
 */
function getSpreadsheet2(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
  return spreadsheet;
}
```

If you paste this script into the (new) Google Apps Script IDE, placing a period (`.`) after `getSpreadsheet1()` will trigger the IDE to display the member functions of class `Spreadsheet`, like `addEditor()`, for the sake of auto-completion. That is to say, the online IDE understands the type of `getSpreadsheet1()`.

I have tried to achieve the same behaviour locally. I copied the script to a local file and I ran `npm i -S @types/google-apps-script` in the same folder, as per [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript). However, I get no autocompletion when placing a period after `getSpreadsheet1()`, but instead I only get it after placing the period after `getSpreadsheet2()`.

Note that my local IDE (VS Code) does understand the type of `SpreadsheetApp.openById('')`, so that does seem to work correctly.

Is there a way to get my local IDE to understand the JSDoc comments that use the types like SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet required by the online IDE?

Comment: It seems my issue can be solved by using the extension ".ts" instead of ".js" for the local file. That is not ideal for me, as `clasp pull` (see [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)) will create ".js" files. So I am still hoping it is possible to achieve this in a different way

Comment: It seems online IDE uses a different type definitions than the community provided one @types/google-apps-script

Comment: But both IDEs work, if you remove the `@return` and leave it  without any type.

Comment: if I recall correctly, the definitions are the same (or at least were pulled initially from the DT repository), however the main namespace (`GoogleAppsScript`) is "unwrapped".

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine  Even if you remove `google-apps-script`, It's not even the same key. `SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet`(which shows it's  a `interface` in apps script online IDE) vs `Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet`

Comment: @TheMaster that's true, I believe the "App" parts are aliased too. However, I can't say for sure if that's the only difference.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine If it's a alias(`SpreadsheetApp` => `Spreadsheet`), that would be fine. But `Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet` isn't even recognized. In online IDE, the namespace for sheets related interfaces is `SpreadsheetApp`. For eg, `SpreadsheetApp.` in jsdoc lists various options like `SpreadsheetApp.Range` instead of  ``SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.Range``( which isn't listed or recognized, when used)

Comment: @TheMaster I just found that adding `declare namespace SpreadsheetApp {type Spreadsheet = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;}` at the start of the file `node_modules/@types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.spreadsheet.d.ts` makes things work for ".js" files locally in the same way that they work in the online IDE. Hopefully this leads to a nice solution

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I think it'll fail with `range`. Online IDE uses: `SpreadsheetApp.Range`, while local uses `GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range`.

Comment: @TheMaster ah yes agreed, the namespace `SpreadsheetApp` I define is incomplete. We could add `type Range = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range` in it and other definitions for `Sheet` etc etc. I was just now looking if maybe it would be possible to "alias a namespace", to maybe fix everything with a single line of typescript code instead of having many aliases, but I am new to typescript.

Comment: Jacob, @OlegValteriswithUkraine said the same. I thought the interface is wrong with many nested levels  obliterated. But maybe I am wrong. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198823/abbreviate-lengthy-typescript-types)  for alias

Comment: @TheMaster I just tested it for `Range`, adding it to my interface seems to work. But yeah it is hard to be sure that everything is the same. It looks like I am using `type` in the same way as in the answer in the Q&A you link to. I was hoping to use something like `type SpreadsheetApp = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet` so that `SpreadsheetApp` is a namespace that is an alias of namespace `GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet`, but that it seems that is not possible. Maybe it is more straightforward to just directly define `SpreadsheetApp`, replacing the definition of `GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides removing the `@returns` completely to let Typescript infer the result type automatically it's possible to make it work in both cases with the following trick:

```js
function caller() {
    getSpreadsheet1();// only the online IDE understands this
    getSpreadsheet2();// only the local IDE (VS Code) understands this
}

/**
 * @typedef {ReturnType<typeof SpreadsheetApp['openById']>} Spreadsheet
 */

/**
 * @returns {Spreadsheet}
 */
function getSpreadsheet1() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
    return spreadsheet;
}

/**
 * @returns {Spreadsheet}
 */
function getSpreadsheet2() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
    return spreadsheet;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting trick. I just found that adding `declare namespace SpreadsheetApp {type Spreadsheet = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;}` at the start of the file `node_modules/@types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.spreadsheet.d.ts` makes things work for ".js" files locally in the same way that they work in the online IDE. I am still processing that new information, I am not sure how that can be used to create an efficient workflow