# GAS/clasp: How do I get autocomplete/intellisense to work in VSCode for 3rd Party libraries

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, visual-studio-code, clasp

I am using VSCode to edit Google App Script (GAS) code with clasp.
I have intellisense working for the core libraries just fine.

(This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/enabling-autocomplete-for-google-apps-script-in-locally-installed-ide) helped)

However, I am also using a [Firestore library](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) in the ScriptApp project and intellisense is not working for the FirestoreApp.

I've tried included the library Javascript code in my project directory and also in the node_modules directory - but no luck.

Does anyone have any tips? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need type definitions file for that library just like https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.spreadsheet.d.ts found in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script If  there isn't any available, you'll create one defining the types.

Comment: No such file in the library to date. Will I have to create a TypeScript file that has an interface defined for each of the objects and functions in the library?

Comment: Yes`````````.`````````

Comment: Thanks. I'll reach out to the library owner first though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3rd Party Libraries, like FirestoreApp, autocompletion does not work.

You will need to create your own `.d.ts` files (optionally added to DefinitelyTyped).

Another option would be to copy/paste the library into your script, and editors like VS Code will provide light autocompletion (1 level deep). The code doesn't need to be in the `node_modules` directory.