# autocompletion of own object after

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete

Is it possible to autcomplete suggetion for properties/methods for own object in google script. 
Suppose I have an object myCar and it has a property name. so after writing myCar. I want to get autocompletion suggests in google script. Can anyone help if it is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling autocomplete for Google Apps Script in locally-installed IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/enabling-autocomplete-for-google-apps-script-in-locally-installed-ide)

Comment: Better way is to use your own ide like vscode with clasp