# Google Apps Script doesn't show the methods when coding

Tags: google-apps-script

Firstly, let me say that I am Spanish so my English is not so good, so please be patient if you find it difficult to understand what I am to say.

Having said that, the problem I have when using Google Apps Script is that the kind of window that is being opened when coding isn't work.

For instance: If I type....     `var doc = documentapp.`   nothing happens, that is, the kind of windows that shows the different methods doesn't even try to open, nothing happens

To help you understand the problem I have, I attached a picture with "what should happen" when coding...

I am in despair.. I don't know what is happening.

If you see the picture, when docfile. is typed a windows is open with different methods, like GetEditors and so on..

Well, that the problem I have, that doesn't happen to me when typing code.

[image: Google AppScript AutoComplete]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Apps Script doesn't show the methods when coding

- This is an auxiliary feature indicating you that something is not correct in your code
- In your particular case: You misspelled `DocumentApp` (case sensitivity is important in Apps Script, so `documentapp` is wrong)
- After you fix the typing mistake, the methods will be shown correctly after the `.` - unless you have some other mistake somewhere else in your code

Comment: You are totally right. My mistake was to think that documentapp will be take by Apps Script the same as DocumentApp. Thanks for your answer. Simple and clear.