# Google Apps Script inheritance on V8

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-runtime

I have recently noticed a weird behaviour of the V8 engine.
When inheriting a class found in a **separated file**, the engine fails to recognise the base class, e.g. the following configuration fails:

BaseFoo.ts

```js
export class BaseFoo {}
```

SpecialFoo.ts

```js
import { BaseFoo } from "./BaseFoo";

class SpecialFoo extends BaseFoo {}
```

with an error:

> ReferenceError: BaseFoo is not defined [line: 1, function: , file: SpecialFoo]

If the two classes are put in the same file, it works.

I am using Visual Studio Code, and it approves this configuration (meaning no typo mistakes).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on their [V8 Runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) page:

> Caution: ES6 modules are not yet supported.

This means exporting and importing of files is not handled by Google Apps Script. This is a bit quirky since all files are in the global scope (and in the order the files are listed) and so you can reference Classes in other files.

Comment: If it helps, I have migrated a Library to V8 + Typescript: [grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) that you can reference. I spent a lot of hours trying to get a lot of `Class` functionality working. I do have some inheritance happening too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Sunny Patel, the V8 runtime does not support modules.
However, you might look into [Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) and its [TypeScript feature](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md), which [partially supports](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md#modules-exports-and-imports) modules.

Related links:

- [Clasp docs on the TypeScript feature](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md)
- [Google's guide to Typescript in Google Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript), in which they suggest to use Clasp.
- [Autocomplete Google Scripts functions in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015874/how-to-enable-autocomplete-for-google-apps-script-in-locally-installed-ide)