# Eslint errors in TypeScript Google Apps Script

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, eslint, clasp

I have a TypeScript project that I push to Google Apps Scripts via [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp).

I'm using functions like `Utilities.formatDate` and `const input = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Paste the URL here.');`.

I see errors like `'Utilities' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)` and `'SpreadsheetApp' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)`.

I don't want to simply disable the `no-undef` rule.

**How can I properly import those dependencies?**

---

Docs:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui

Comment: Did you install the types?

Comment: @TheMaster I had installed `"@types/google-apps-script": "^1.0.50",` in my `package.json` but `"types": ["google-apps-script"]` was what I was missing from my `tsconfig.json`. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51772127/470749