# Importing moment.js in transpiled Apps Script

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

I have the necessity of using moment.js inside a locally developed Apps Script project, which uses [google\clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) to convert from TypeScript.

I have already tried adding the js library inside the project as I do when writing normally in .gs, but using clasp doesn't seem to permit me to use that way.

I have already tried, as I read a lot in other Stack Overflow answers, to use `eval` like this without success:

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('library.min.js url').getContentText());
```

In all the cases, after I pushed to Apps Script and run the function in the Apps Script Editor, I receive

> ReferenceError: "moment" is not defined. (row 6, file "Test")

My TS file:
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: The screenshot of code is an exemplification of the issue. This is because the issue is not directly related to the code I wrote as you can assume looking at the code.

Comment: The important code part is under code tag as rules ask

Comment: Writing your code here yields **"Cannot find name 'moment'"**, not  **`ReferenceError: "moment" is not defined`**. Have you described this issue properly? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have modified now the question to be more clear on that step.
That error is provided to me on the Google Script page after compiling from TypeScript.

Comment: Seem that the issue is caused by the line `var module = module || { exports: exports };` that **ts2gas** add all the time as part of the transpile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use external libraries like Moment.js via `eval` & `UrlFetchApp` in the "standard" Apps Script projects because the variables `exports` and `module` are not defined, so the library [installs itself into the global context](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/e1601867b9bc1d86273c08b8d97182e1cf66c689/moment.js#L3-L6)

Indeed, we can verify the result by inspecting `this` in the Apps Script Editor:

#### Code.gs

```
var momentURL = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js";
function main() {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(momentURL).getContentText());
  Logger.log(this["moment"]);
}
```

Executing `main` yields

```
function e() {
    return Qe.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

For transpiled TypeScript, because `exports` and `module` are globally defined, the initialization of `eval`'d libraries assumes that it has a more recent runtime / package management system than that provided by Google Apps Script.

#### Code.ts

```
import * as moment from "moment";

const momentURL = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js";
function main() {
    eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(momentURL).getContentText());
    Logger.log(`this['moment']: ${this["moment"]}`);
    Logger.log(`this.module: ${this.module}`);
    for (let key in this.module)
        Logger.log(`this.module[${key}]: ${this.module[key]}`);
}
```

`$ clasp push` -->

#### Code.gs

```
// Compiled using ts2gas 1.6.0 (TypeScript 3.2.2)
var exports = exports || {};
var module = module || { exports: exports };
//import * as moment from "moment";
var momentURL = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js";
function main() {
    eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(momentURL).getContentText());
    Logger.log("this['moment']: " + this["moment"]);
    Logger.log("this.module: " + this.module);
    for (var key in this.module)
        Logger.log("this.module[" + key + "]: " + this.module[key]);
}
```

Which yields a log of

```
this['moment']: undefined
this.module: [object Object]
this.module[exports]: 
function e() {
    return Qe.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

---

### Solutions

So the `eval` is successful, but binds to `module.exports` and not `moment`. You can (in the transpiled Apps Script) refer to `module.exports` instead of `moment`:

```
Logger.log(module.exports().format("YYYY")); // 2019
```

Probably you will need to use a different method than clasp, since it seems `ts2gas` (as of v1.6.0) does not support [import / export transpiling](https://github.com/grant/ts2gas/issues/26). This observed behavior wherein `module.exports` in transpiled TS is the eval'd import seems heinously fragile, and will certainly not be easy to work around when writing the actual TypeScript.

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803793/9337071
- https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/325